# Problem with Geomesa Kafka Consumers

Tags: geomesa

I'm trying Geomesa Kafka and the GeoMesa Kafka Quick Start tutorial.
The producer writes features into Kafka data store and I can see new records in my Kafka topic.
However, my consumer

```
...
SimpleFeatureSource consumerFS = consumer.getFeatureSource(sft.getTypeName());
...
try (SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = consumerFS.getFeatures().features()) {
                System.out.println("Current consumer state:");
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(DataUtilities.encodeFeature(iterator.next()));
                }
            }
```

every time returns empty iterator ( iterator.hasNext()=null ).

What could be the reason?

P.S. Writing records to the producer's datastore, causes following WARN message:

```
o.l.g.f.k.s.KryoUserDataSerialization$   : Skipping serialization of entry: USE_PROVIDED_FID -> true
```

Comment: Which version of GeoMesa are you using?  Also, which version of Kafka?

Comment: Kafka 2.5.0, Geomesa 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @GeoMesaJim it looks like a compatibility problem. I've just tried Geomessa with Kafka 2.1.1 and 2.2.1. Everything works fine. The problem appears on 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks.  GeoMesa 3.0 is compiled with Kafka 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.  Kafka 2.5 is the first Kafka version without Scala 2.11 supports.  That may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, it is important to ensure that the versions of all components are compatible.

Quote @GeoMesaJim:

> GeoMesa 3.0 is compiled with Kafka 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11. Kafka 2.5 is the first Kafka version without Scala 2.11 supports.